# What are the equivalent user accounts for IIS/ASP.NET in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

In IIS we have a series of accounts an application pool can run under:

- Network Service
- Application Pool Identity
- Custom User
- etc

My question is if I have a site hosted on an Azure App Service do I have the equivalent accounts to choose from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such a thing. The closest would be managed identity / service principal, where you create an account in your Azure AD and assign it to your application.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview

Comment: thanks, this pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

In azure it has 2 option using managed identity ( particular user) and service principal account where you can go and register application in ad and give permission to your application.